# Merging the 2 lists into 1 which are values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello all I am very new to the programming.

I have a dictC

dictC = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[5,6,7,8,9,10]}

I want my output like

mergedlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Could any one help me with the logic to define a function?

I have tried some thing like this

enter code here
dictC = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'b': [3, 7, 8, 9, 10]}

```
result = MergeDictValues(dictC)

print result
```

dictC = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'b': [3, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    dictc= (dictC.values())

```
dictc.extend(dictc)

print dictc
```

def MergeDictValues(inputDict):
    resultList = []
    mergedList = # I am missing my logic here 
    mergedList.extend( )
return resultList()

```
MergeDictValues(dictc)

resultList= MergeDictValues(dictc)

print resultList
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please show your latest attempt and explain what difficulties you are having?

Comment: #dictC = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'b': [3, 7, 8, 9, 10]}



#result = MergeDictValues(dictC)
#print result
dictC = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'b': [3, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
dictc= (dictC.values())
#dictc.extend(dictc)

print dictc

def MergeDictValues(inputDict):
    resultList = []
    mergedList = w
    mergedList.extend( )
    return resultList()
MergeDictValues(dictc)
resultList= MergeDictValues(dictc)
print resultList

Comment: Update your question and put that code in there using the formatting tools please.

Comment: hello idjaw,    I tried to do the above like i ev pasted above. Is it hte right way to proceed ?

Comment: As mentioned, please put that code in your original question and make sure it is properly formatted using the formatting tools. Posting code in the comments is illegible

Comment: You need to provide more details as well because it seems like you want to also remove repeated values? This is unclear.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question Sir,

Comment: I had to rollback your edit. Please use the formatting tools to ensure that the code is formatted exactly as it is in your editor. There seem to be indentation issues happening and not sure what is a real representation.

Comment: I've rolled it back to revision `4`.  @AnikethChepuri edit your question and *format you code*. You are making it *very hard* for people to help you.

Comment: Is it fine now ?? or still am missing the exact format ?? I am sorry actually this is my first post i am facing problem with the way it should be posted thank u

Comment: Take a look at the way your question looks. Does it seem like all code segments are highlighted? No, it really doesn't. Take a look at *[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)* and come back and fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
mergedlist = dictC['a']+ dictC['b']
```

edit - wait - do you know there are repeated elements in the list( last element of list 1 is 5, but so is the first element of list 2) - is this an invariant feature of the data. More info required I think..

Comment: hello I have posted the code which is formatted . Thank you

Comment: are you expecting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10] as your final list?

Answer (score 0):

```
def MergeDictValues(dictC):
    return [x for y in dictC.values() for x in y]
```

Input :

```
dictC = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[5,6,7,8,9,10]}
MergeDictValues(dictC)
```

Out put :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you Hamza !!

Answer (score 0):

Pythons dicts are unordered. If you iterate over the keys, you should sort them first. You might get `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as a result otherwise.

You could use a double list comprehension :

```
dictC = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[5,6,7,8,9,10]}
print([x for key in sorted(dictC) for x in dictC[key]])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

or `sum` to add the lists:

```
print(sum([dictC[key] for key in sorted(dictC)], []))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```